# Discord JS - How to react multiple times to the same embed?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I've only gotten the first **"moneybag"** emoji to react to the newest message in the channel, which is the embed that the bot sends, however, I want the bot to react to the new embed with both the **"money bag"** and **"ticket"** emojis and so far it will react with the **"money bag"** emoji but, errors out when it tries to react with the **"ticket"** emoji. How do I get the bot to react to the new embed with both emojis?

```
    if (message.content === '-new') {

        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
        };

        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()

        .setTitle('Ticket')

        .setColor('DC3BF5')

        .setDescription('Thank you for showing interest in purchasing a commission from the Quadra Build Team, or for lending us your time through Support. Make sure you have read our #terms-of-service channel before requesting a commission. We are glad to make your prolific ideas & requests come true!\n\n If you accidentally created a ticket by mistake, use (-del) to delete the ticket.\n\n React with :moneybag: to order a Commission.\n React with :tickets: to create a Support Ticket.\n -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')

    message.channel.send(embed)
    .then(m => m.react(''))
    .then(m => m.react(''))
    .catch(m => {

        console.error('Emoji failed to react.');
    });
    message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 0, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {

            collected.on('collect', () => {

                m.clearReactions();

                var secondEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()

                .setTitle('Ticket')

                .setColor('DC3BF5')

                .setDescription('lol')
            });
        } else {

            collected.on('collect', () => {

                m.clearReactions();

                var secondEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()

                .setTitle('Ticket')

                .setColor('DC3BF5')

                .setDescription('lol 2')
            });
        }
    })
    .catch(collected => {
        message.channel.send('You didn\'t react with either of the specified emojis.');
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the error

Comment: It runs the console error **"Emoji faile to react."**

Comment: Could you try to get rid of the ``.catch(m => {

        console.error('Emoji failed to react.');
    });`` and tell us what the actual error is?

Comment: Removed the .catch statement, and the error now is that "m.react is not a statement.". M is supposed to be an identifier for Javascript I believe, but its purpose in this code is to make sure the bot reacts to the embed it sent, instead of the user's message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Message#react returns a MessageReaction in a promise so you need to do:

```
message.channel.send(embed)
    .then(m => m.react(''))
    .then(m => m.message.react(''))
```

or

```
message.channel.send(embed)
    .then(m => {
        m.react('')
        m.react('')
     });
```

or with async await:

```
const m = await message.channel.send(embed);
await m.react('')
await m.react('')
```

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it :)

Comment: Thank you too Plasma! :D

Answer (score 3):

the first `.then()` actually returns a MessageReaction object, which is why you're getting this error (can't call `.react()` on a MessageReaction).

You could **1. Use async/wait**

```
async function() {
const embed = await message.channel.send('test')
await embed.react('')
await embed.react('')
}
```

or **2. Use the `message` property of `MessageReaction`**

```
message.channel.send(embed)
    .then(m => m.react(''))
    .then(r => r.message.react(''))
```

Comment: Thank you Francois!