# Discord.js How do I get the bot to react to the message it just sent in discord by id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

How do I get the bot to react to the message it just sent in discord by id?

In this case, I already got the message id:

```
        if(inf.t !== "MESSAGE_UPDATE") return
        let here = inf.d.id;
         if(inf.d.id === `${here}`){
        message.channel.send(`${here}`);
        message.react("✅"); //this react is just to this reaction is only in 
                            //the message that I sent the command
         }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.then()`, like so:

```
message.channel.send(here).then(m => m..react("✅"))
```

[more on .then() here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: thanks. And what i do if I want to add another reaction with this one?

Comment: I'll redirect you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58035200/11898989)